# How to retrieve unique records having unique values in two columns from a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to query a table where I need the result that contains unique values from two columns together. For e.g.

Table

```
EnquiryId  |  EquipmentId | Price
-----------+--------------+-------
    1      |       E20    |  10
    1      |       E50    |  40
    1      |       E60    |  20   
    2      |       E30    |  90
    2      |       E20    |  10
    2      |       E90    |  10
    3      |       E90    |  10
    3      |       E60    |  10
```

For each `EnquiryId, EquipmentId` will be unique in the table. Now I want a result where I can get something like this

```
  EnquiryId  |  EquipmentId | Price
  -----------+--------------+-------
    1        |     E20      |  10        
    2        |     E30      |  90        
    3        |     E90      |  10
```

In the result each `enquiryId` present in the table should be displayed uniquely.

If suppose I have 3 `EquipmentIds` "E20,E50,E60" for `EnquiryId` "1".. Any random `EquipmentId` should be displayed from these three values only.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens, if 3 set of EnquiryId comes with E20 and E50?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **QUERY**

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (PARTITION BY enquiryID 
    ORDER BY enquiryID ) AS RN
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT enquiryID,equipmentID,Price
FROM cte     
WHERE RN=1
```

### **[FIND FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0fc4/1)**

Answer (score 1):

The following code must help you..
Sorry that I ended up in a lengthy solution only. Run it in your SSMS and see the result.

```
Declare @tab table (EnquiryId int,  EquipmentId varchar(10),Price int)
Insert into @tab values

    (1,'E20',10),
    (1,'E50',40),
    (1,'E60',20),   
    (2,'E30',90),
    (2,'E20',10),
    (2,'E90',10),
    (3,'E90',10),
    (3,'E60',10)
----------------------------------------------
Declare @s int = 1
Declare @e int,@z varchar(10)

Declare @Equipment table (EquipmentId varchar(10),ind int)
Insert into @Equipment (EquipmentId) Select Distinct EquipmentId From @tab

Declare @Enquiry table (id int identity(1,1),EnquiryId int,EquipmentId varchar(10))
Insert into @Enquiry (EnquiryId) Select Distinct EnquiryId From @tab

Set @e = @@ROWCOUNT

While @s <= @e
begin
    Select  Top 1 @z = T.EquipmentId
    From    @tab T
    Join    @Enquiry E On T.EnquiryId = E.EnquiryId
    Join    @Equipment Eq On Eq.EquipmentId = T.EquipmentId
    Where   E.id = @s
    And     Eq.ind is Null
    Order by NEWID()

    update  @Enquiry
    Set     EquipmentId = @z
    Where   id = @s

    update  @Equipment
    Set     ind = 1
    Where   EquipmentId = @z

Set @s = @s + 1
End

Select  T.EnquiryId,T.EquipmentId,T.Price
From    @tab T
left join @Enquiry E on T.EnquiryId = E.EnquiryId
Where   T.EquipmentId = E.EquipmentId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY (Typical way) to remove duplicate value.

Basic steps are:

1. Alter table & Add Identity Column.
2. Group by columns which can be dupicate.
3. Delete those record.

Check here [Remove Duplicate Rows from a Table in SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157977/Remove-Duplicate-Rows-from-a-Table-in-SQL-Server)